# Is there any way No Correlation need for JMeter Script?

Tags: jmeter

Is there an script recorder for JMeter (jmx) in which No Correlation is NOT needed. Just like "TruClient" Protocol in LoadRunner.
The script created with TruClient does not require any Correlation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few options available.

Please check

1. [JCorrelate](https://www.jmxenhancer.com/jcorrelate.html)
   [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ta1urDI49R4)
2. Blazemeter [Auto correlation Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder/blob/master/README.md)
   [Detailed article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-jmeter-correlation-recorder-plugin)

[Naveen has explained the process in this video](https://youtu.be/u3QkjkrzO5U)

3. Ubik auto [correlation plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-autocorrelator-plugin-help/) for

Answer (score 0):

`TruClient` is not a "protocol", LoadRunner just launches a real browser (a [headless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) one) and controls it.

JMeter equivalent would be [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), if you're looking for recording solution for Selenium the options are in:

- [Selenium IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/)
- [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium)

However be informed that real browsers are quite resource intensive, for example [Firefox 95](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/95.0/system-requirements/) needs a CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance so for 100 users you will need 101 CPUs and 200 GB of RAM which is kind of expensive.

Moreover:

- As per WebDriver Sampler [introduction](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Introduction)

  > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.
- As per Selenium [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

  > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

So I would recommend keeping your test on HTTP protocol level without browsers involved, if you have problems with implementing correlation - take a look at [BlazeMeter Test Recorder capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" format](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters.